# How can I use rv_continuous to generate random samples from a gaussian kde?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics

I've been stuck on this for awhile now. Here's my problem: I have a set of observed data. I want to turn this data into a pmf, use a gaussian kernel density estimator to estimate a continuous pdf from this observed data, and then be able to sample from that pdf.

I am using Scipy, and have managed to get the kernel density estimation to work. I think what I need to sample from it is to subclass rv_continuous and overwrite the _pdf method by returning the evaluation of my kernel density estimation. However, when I try to define the kernel density estimation in my rv_continuous class' **init** method, I am unable to call .rvs() on the resulting class to sample from it. But when I define a function separately and call this function independently in the rv_continuous class' _pdf method, it works fine.

This sounds confusing, I know, but see what I'm talking about in the code below.

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde, rv_continuous
import numpy.random as npr

# Create fake data just to test if this works
test_data = [0, 8, 12, 35, 40, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0]
output = []
for entry in test_data:    
    number_obs = entry
    for i in range(number_obs):
        mao = npr.uniform()
        output.append(mao)

# First, what I would like to work
class mao_pdf(rv_continuous):
    """
    Class for creating a pdf, round-by-round, from which samples may be drawn.
    """
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(rv_continuous, self).__init__()
        self.kde = gaussian_kde(data, bw_method = 0.18)

    def _pdf(self, x):
        return self.kde.evaluate(x)[0]

pdf = mao_pdf(output)
print(pdf.rvs()) # This does not work

# Now, what paradoxically works (but is really the exact same thing
# just in a convoluted way)
test_kde = gaussian_kde(output, bw_method = 0.18)

def f(x):
    return test_kde.evaluate(x)[0]

class test_pdf(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        return f(x)

pdf = test_pdf(a = 0, b = 1)
print(pdf.rvs()) # This one works
```

So it seems like it might have something to do with the bounds (setting a = 0, b = 1), but for the life of me I cannot figure out why this is so critical or how to even implmement this in my class mao_pdf. I tried just defining `self.a = 0` and `self.b = 1` in the `__init__()` method of my mao_pdf class, but that did not work.

This really should not be so complicated, I'm just trying to turn actual observed data into a sample-able continuous probability density function. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's very simple to sample from a KDE distribution, without having to calculate the PDF for the KDE:

1. Choose a data point uniformly at random (with replacement).
2. Add a normally distributed random number to the data point, with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation equal to the bandwidth.

In fact, this distribution can be sampled even without SciPy, as long as you know the bandwidth:

```
import numpy

gen=numpy.random.Generator(npr.PCG64())
test_data = [0, 8, 12, 35, 40, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0]
# Choose 10 data points from `test_data` at random.
c=gen.integers(0, len(test_data), size=10)
c=numpy.asarray([float(test_data[d]) for d in c])
# Add a Gaussian jitter.
# Use the bandwidth factor in your example.
c+=gen.normal(0, 0.18)
```

Note that the code above requires NumPy 1.17 or later, which includes an [improved system for random number generation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/). If you must still use NumPy 1.16 or earlier, the following code can be used:

```
import numpy

gen=numpy.random.Generator(npr.PCG64())
test_data = [0, 8, 12, 35, 40, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0]
c=numpy.random.uniform(0, 10, size=10)
c=numpy.asarray([float(test_data[int(d)]) for d in c])
c+=numpy.random.normal(0, 0.18) # Use the bandwidth factor in your example
```